# I want to "insert record to room database" -> "Api call " -> "Update local record"

Tags: android, android-room, rx-java2, reactivex, flatmap

I am new to rxjava android. I want to insert record in local room database. I set auto generate true so it will generate id for me. Then I want to make api call to send that record to server. After I get success in api call I want to update previously added record in my local database with serverId which I am getting from server. I know that I can achive this sequence using rxjava flatmap but I don't know how.

here is my insert method which returns id

```
@Insert
Single<Long> insertMessage(ChatMessage chatMessage);
```

here is my api call

```
@POST(ApiConstants.API_CHAT_SEND_MESSAGE)
Single<SendMessageResponse> sendChatMessage(@Body PostChatMessage postChatMessage);
```

and here is my update method

```
@Query("UPDATE message SET id = :id WHERE localId = :idToUpdate")
Single<Integer> updateMessage(String id, int idToUpdate);
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: You are on the right track with your idea to use `flatMap`. Have you tried that out?

Comment: Not sure if I can achieve this using flatmap or I need to chain operations. Also I am not fundamentally clear in rxjava. I tried to write code but it gives errors

Comment: You can also listen for database changes and then find out those that don't have a `serverId` and make requests, because bear in mind that you can add to the database while you're offline, and it's good to separate the Rx chain here to discern whether adding to the database failed or the network request failed. You might be trying to reinvent the wheel here though, have you looked at https://github.com/dropbox/Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tired this way for me its working fine and gave me expected result

```
 messageDao.insertMessage(chatMessage)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMap(id -> {
                    return ApiServiceClient.getApiServiceNew().sendChatMessage(postChatMessage).flatMap(sendMessageResponse -> {
                        messageDao.updateMessage(sendMessageResponse.getData().getId(), id);
                        return Single.just(id);
                    });
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(new SingleObserver<Long>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Long aLong) {
                        Log.d(TAG,"Record updated"+aLong);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.d(TAG,"Record Failed"+e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
```